# Python: How to get a client file to send and receive a message via UDP?

Tags: python, network-programming, udp, ip

I'm working from the textbook "Computer Networking: A Top-down Approach" by Kurose and Ross.

In it (Section 2.7) it goes through sample code for a python program.

UDPClient.py

```
from socket import *
serverName = ‘hostname’
serverPort = 12000
clientSocket = socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
message = raw_input(’Input lowercase sentence:’)
clientSocket.sendto(message,(serverName, serverPort))
modifiedMessage, serverAddress = clientSocket.recvfrom(2048)
print modifiedMessage
clientSocket.close()
```

UDPServer.py

```
from socket import *
serverPort = 12000
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
serverSocket.bind((’’, serverPort))
print ”The server is ready to receive”
while 1:
        message, clientAddress = serverSocket.recvfrom(2048)
        modifiedMessage = message.upper()
        serverSocket.sendto(modifiedMessage, clientAddress)
```

I initially encountered errors which I solved by reading others' questions on this same code on here. Remove the ('socket.' from the paramters in line 4)

UDPClient.py

```
from socket import *
serverName = 'hostname'
serverPort = 12000
clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
message = raw_input('Input lowercase sentence:')
clientSocket.sendto(message,(serverName, serverPort))
modifiedMessage, serverAddress = clientSocket.recvfrom(2048)
print modifiedMessage
clientSocket.close()
```

Running python UDPClient.py on this updated code results in the following error...

```
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

I believe this is due to the 'hostname' in line 2. Answers to the other question say there should be an IP address in its place (which the textbook also suggests) and one answer said replacing it with the empty string '' worked.

However, whenever I try the empty string or an IP address it doesn't seem to do anything? It doesn't give an error but neither does it return anything or finish processing the command. Regardless of whether I run UPDServer.py first or not. I believe I'm missing something or not understanding something... how do I know what IP to use? Is the IP (or lack of) likely the reason why it is not working? And if so, what IP should I use and how should I go about running both the UDPClient and UDPServer programs?

Comment: Try `telnet localhost 80` and tell me what happens

Comment: @Arman That seemed to do the trick, thanks. Funny thing was I'd actually tried using that IP as it was suggested on another post. However, I think the reason it hadn't worked before was because I was running the client before I ran the server. Running the server first seemed to solve it.

Comment: @Arman That command results in "Trying 127.0.0.1... telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused"

Comment: There is a problem with your localhost , Is there any service or application use it  ? try shut down the user of localhost and then try again

Comment: How do I do this? Bare in mind I'm on my university's computers - I don't know if that affects anything. Important thing is it worked when I ran UDPServer prior to running UDPClient using the local IP address.

Comment: Just go to port lists and check port 80 , google it how to find port lists , no , there isn't any special here for public computer